# Pandas truth value of a series is ambiguous

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe. I want to check the value in a particular column and create a flag column  based on if it is null/not null.

df_have:

```
A     B
1     
2     X
```

df_want

```
A    B   B_Available
1          N
2    X     Y
```

I did:

```
def chkAvail(row):
    return (pd.isnull(row['B']) == False)

if (df_have.apply (lambda row: chkAvail(row),axis=1)):
    df_want['B_Available']='Y'
```

I got:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
df['B_available'] = df.B.notnull().map({False: 'N', True:'Y'})
```

If blank values are `NaN` or `None`. If they are whitespaces, do

```
df['B_available'] =  (df.B != ' ').map({False: 'N', True:'Y'})
```

---

To do `if series` is not a good idea because there might be many `True` and `False` in series. E.g. what does `if pd.Series([True, False, True, True])` mean? Makes no sense ;)

Comment: Thank you. But I am passing a row (axis=1) to my function. And within the row, I am selecting a column :row['B']. So the function applies to a column value, not a Series. What is my mistake?

Comment: `df.apply (lambda row: chkAvail(row),axis=1)` returns a `Series`. Check the output with `print`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
# In case blank values are NaN
df['B_Available'] = np.select([df.B.isnull()], ['N'], 'Y')

# In case blank values are empty strings:
df['B_Available'] = np.select([df.B == ''], ['N'], 'Y')

>>> df
   A    B B_Available
0  1  NaN           N
1  2    X           Y
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `np.where`

```
df['B_Available']=np.where(df.B.eq(''),'N','Y')
df
Out[86]: 
   A  B B_Available
0  1              N
1  2  X           Y
```